# apache poi Chinese automatically adjusts column width

Tags: apache-poi

Apache poi Chinese automatic column width adjustment is inaccurate

when there is chinese

How should I set it up so that it can adjust the Chinese column width correctly？

Some of my columns here don't have Chinese characters, so I can't expand them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI uses [SheetUtil](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_5/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/SheetUtil.java?view=markup) to calculate the needed cell width dependent on text. This uses [TextLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html). But until now it not differs between default text glyph having `TextAttribute.WIDTH_REGULAR` and others, such as CJKV (Chinese, Japanese, Korean and Vietnamese) ideographs or miscellaneous symbols and pictographs or ..., which need much more extended width.

One could patch `org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil` to have a method:

```java
/**
 * Set text TextAttribute.WIDTH to Java2D AttributedString dependent on whether character is ideographic 
 * or miscellaneous symbols and pictographs
 * or ...
 */
private static void setTextAttributeWidth(String txt, AttributedString str) {
    float textAttributeWidth = 0.0f;
    int codePoints = 0;
    for (int offset = 0; offset < txt.length(); ) {
        int codePoint = txt.codePointAt(offset);
        if (Character.isIdeographic(codePoint)) { // if the specified character (Unicode code point) is a CJKV (Chinese, Japanese, Korean and Vietnamese) ideograph
            textAttributeWidth += (TextAttribute.WIDTH_REGULAR * 2.25);  
        } else if (codePoint >= 0x1F000 && codePoint <= 0x1FFFF) { // if in code point range 0x1F000 to 0x1FFFF; miscellaneous symbols and pictographs
            textAttributeWidth += (TextAttribute.WIDTH_REGULAR * 3.0);  
        } else if (false /*ToDo ... other things*/) {
            //textAttributeWidth += /*ToDo*/;  
        } else {
            textAttributeWidth += TextAttribute.WIDTH_REGULAR;
        }
        offset += Character.charCount(codePoint);
        codePoints++;
    }
    textAttributeWidth = textAttributeWidth / codePoints;
    str.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WIDTH, textAttributeWidth);
}
```

which gets called always when `copyAttributes(font, str, 0, txt.length());` gets called:

```java
...
AttributedString str = new AttributedString(txt);
setTextAttributeWidth(txt, str);
copyAttributes(font, str, 0, txt.length());
...
```

That would be the place to differ between default text glyph having `TextAttribute.WIDTH_REGULAR` and others, which need much more extended width.

I have tried this and got reliable results when auto sizing cells having string contents like:

```java
...
String[] testStrings = new String[] {
    "default text",
    "用中文說「世界你好」",
    "lorem default text ipsum",
    "lorem 用中文說「世界你好」 ipsum",
    "‍↔️",   
    "lorem ‍↔️ ipsum"   
};
...
```